# What is the expected number of turns for two dots to meet

Tags: probability, expectation

Let's say I have a circle with $r$ dots $0,...,r-1$. I drop pin $1$ at a random dot $i$ on the circle and pin $2$ at a random dot $j$ in the circle. Now I rotate pin $1$ clockwise moving it one step clockwise at a turn and I rotate pin $2$ clockwise $2$ pints ever turn. How can I calculate the expected number of turns I do until both pins meet for the very first time?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: As a hint to get started, the numbering of the dots is arbitrary here so you may as well assume that pin $2$ starts at dot $0$.  If, then pin $1$ starts at dot $n$ can you work out how many turns it takes?

Comment: Well I  tried writing the states transfer as a matrix of $r \times r$ but i didn't see any clear patterns for me to calculate the Markov chain. Perhaps I am over complicating things and there is a more simple way or arguing it?

Comment: @AspiringMat I just removed the MarkovChain tag ... you are indeed making it completely too difficult! Look at lulu's hint: if the 2-pin is $n$ points behind the $1$-pin, in how many turns will the $2$-pin have caught up with the $1$-pin?

Comment: Thanks, got it now!

Comment: @AspiringMat You're welcome! Sometimes you just have to use your common sense rather than heavy mathematical tools :)

Answer (score 2):

Moving pin $1$ clockwise at a rate of $1$, and pin $2$ clockwise at a rate of $2$ is the same as keeping pin $1$ still, and moving pin $2$ clockwise at a rate of $2-1=1$. Does that help? Do you know how to do the expected value calculation from there? Just think of pin $1$ as fixed, and think about the number of steps to reach it from all of the different places pin $2$ could land.